# AVAudioSession -> switching to ear piece working differently in ios 16 and IOS 15 or less devices

Tags: avaudiosession

i am not able to understand why the behaviour is different in IOS 16 and IOS 15.5 or less.

i am switching to ear piece once the call gets connected(it is received in handler). once i received the status, using the following method, i changed to ear piece

let options = AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker

```
     do {
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredInput(nil)
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.none)
         try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord,mode: .voiceChat, options: options)

     } catch {
        print("Could not set up session: error: \(error)")
     }
```

it seems working fine in IOS 15 or less device but not in others. Anyone have any idea?